# GWT: Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, html, gwt

I'm facing this problem: after clicking on a button, I make a request to the server and get some data; then, I display the data on a new page/view. This raises a problem: the UI has to wait while the request is being made and data is being received, parsed and set on the view. This results in the user having to wait until all the data is loaded before even being able to go back, and doesn't even have the chance to cancel the call. Multithreading would solve the issue, and that's where I need help.

The HTML5 Web Workers would do the trick for me, however I don't want to "hard code" them in JSNI and have all the calls written with Javascript instead of GWT Java (RequestBuilder). I've read about DeferredCommand but I also don't think it's the answer to my issue.

Any suggestions? Or this is an impossible optimization, at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS, therefore GWT, there is no multithreading. Instead you should use asynchronous calls with callbacks. Normally when you use [GWT RPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) for communication, you issue a request and handle result in `onSuccess` event. Alternatively you can always use [`Timer`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html) to check for result periodically. I'm not sure what kind of request you are making, so hard to be specific. Probably you should check appropriate section of [Communicating with the server](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/clientserver.html)

**EDIT:** I've just noticed you mention [RequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html). The sendRequest() should not block execution and you should process result in `RequestCallback.onResponseReceived()` of provided callback. Which mean you somehow continue your button event handling in that callback.